# Jmeter multiple log in token

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am a newbie using JMeter. I am trying to test multiple user log in. As of now, I only have 10 users to test. My problem is, when I use only one credentials, test is more slower. However, when I try with 10 different user credentials by using csv data set config, it gets done faster(I also deleted "_token" parameter from parameters).

[image]

[image]

How am I gonna **capture the tokens for each user?** I've also added HTTP Cookie Manager on top of steps.

[image]

I am not sure how to do for multiple log in. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be deleting the `_token` from parameters, most probably you need to:

1. Extract it from the previous response `Log_in_get` using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. Replace the hard-coded value with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the previous step

JMeter variables are local for the threads so each thread (virtual user) will have its own token.

The process of handling dynamic data in JMeter tests is known as **correlation** and there is a lot of information over the web covering this topic, i.e. [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)